# Finance with the multitude of "Secure Browsers"

Tags: web-browser, financial

[Thanks for the great answers! But it was put on hold so I've edited my question to be a lot less opinion-based. Based on the answers already given, though, I am getting the sense that booting off a LiveCD with an updated installation of Chrome is probably the best option. :P]

For the following:

- Kaspersky Safe Money
- Avast SafeZone
- BitDefender SafePay
- etc.

I don't know where I can look up the software specs: Which of these use a fresh VM every startup? Which are capable of preventing keylogging? How well do each of these track the main Chromium (or Firefox or whatever) branch? What other good security features do these have?

Comment: I'm not sure Incognito mode belongs on your list - it is not a security mode of operation. As for the specific question of fresh VM and keylogging, those details will be available from the vendor. As for "which is most secure", you don't define what you want to secure against and it is very open-ended and opinion-based.

Comment: you might want to be careful with Whitehat Aviator.  Not sure on its current status but a couple of months back there were some issues... https://plus.google.com/+JustinSchuh/posts/69qw9wZVH8z

Answer (score 4):

The challenge with any non-mainstream browser is that writing a browser engine from scratch is a complex and expensive process, and maintaining a fork of a browser and tracking upstream is also a complex process, especially once the fork starts to deviate significantly from the base project.

If you look at the problems that [WhiteHat aviator](https://github.com/WhiteHatSecurity/Aviator) encountered [earlier this year](https://plus.google.com/+JustinSchuh/posts/69qw9wZVH8z) and the fact that it's no longer maintained by [WhiteHat](https://www.whitehatsec.com/aviator/), you can see an example of the possible issues.

Not to say that I think it's impossible for someone to do a good job of creating a browser more focused on security, but that it may be hard for the company doing it to dedicate more resource to security than the mainstream browser developers already do (from that google plus post, the chrome team have 30 full-time security people).

Personally I'd recommend using an up to date platform with decent security tools and, if you're specifically concerned, consider having a device or VM dedicated to financial transactions, to separate it out from other browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is simply "nobody knows". Let's make some large assumptions:

1. Endpoint is not currently compromised.
2. Financial Institution to transact with is not currently compromised.
3. No exploits known *today* (tomorrow another story) for home router OS, OS, installed applications, and firmware.

Then the most secure app / browser in your list will be the one that:

1. Has no zero days (tomorrow another story, difficult to know or measure)
2. Has no known vulnerabilities (tomorrow another story, vetted through vulnerability assessment)
3. Has been secure code reviewed and pen tested by a qualified entity and received a score (tomorrow another story, but fewer issues = better score, quality of tests dependent on skill of testers)

Assuming the first 3 points above, I would use an always current and updated live CD on a physical machine or VM to conduct financial transaction if I'm worried.

In addition, I would not do business with financial companies that can't even keep an A on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and do not offer 2-factor authentication.

Comment: 2 thoughts: A) in my experience, banks outside the USA do not have 2fa on their websites, so boycotting banks isn't really an option for most of us. B) Your first 3. is a HUGE assumption. I generally prefer to assume that my environment does have 0-days and then ask what protection the app can offer me despite that.

Comment: A.) Banks outside of the USA do in fact have 2FA enabled - I live outside of the US and use them daily. Why do you believe that only the USA offers 2FA?However, point taken that not every organisation has 2FA enabled so one might not have a choice.

Comment: Fine I'll soften. I live in Canada and have never interacted with a bank that offers 2FA for their web banking. In fact, I recently refused to accept online statements when the only way to retrieve them was to enroll for web-banking with a password that had to be 8 characters.